# Wrap an Element around another Element

Tags: jquery, dart

Is there an easy way to wrap an [Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html), as there is in jQuery ( [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) ).

**Example:**

In jQuery:

```
$('.inner').wrap('<div />');
```

What I'm looking for in Dart:

```
query('.inner').wrap(new DivElement());
```

where the HTML could look like

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="inner"> Some text </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the result would be

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="inner"> Some text </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that this function is already available, but it looks like a usefull feature. You could create a feature request here: http://dartbug.com/new

Comment: I've created a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11765&thanks=11765

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a naive implementation of a `wrap()` function that may meet your needs:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <p class='first'></p>

    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'dart:html';

      wrap(Element element, Element wrapper) {
        var clone = element.clone(true);
        element.replaceWith(wrapper);
        wrapper.children.add(clone);
      }

      void main() {
        wrap(query('p.first'), new DivElement());
      }
    </script>

    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After calling `wrap()`, the DOM looks like this:

```
<div>
  <p class='first'></p>
</div>
```

One thing (at least) to watch out for, though: cloning a node does not copy event listeners added using `listen()` (`elem.onClick.listen`, for example) or those assigned directly to element properties. This is not an issue with the simple example I use here, but could be a problem in some cases.

Based on Alexandre's comment, here is another way to wrap an element. This one does not clone the element:

```
wrap2(Element element, Element wrapper) {
  element.parent.insertBefore(wrapper, element);
  wrapper.children.add(element);
}
```

I don't know if either solution works out of the box for all situations, but they work with the examples here.

Comment: Is it needed to clone `element` ? I don't think so.

Comment: No, I suppose it isn't. I'm adding a second solution that does not use clone.

Comment: I see another problem (maybe?) - what if the argument `wrapper` already has a parent?

Comment: I assumed that the wrapper was an unattached DOM node. Of course, if it is a DOM element, things get a little trickier.